# How to print each element of a data frame with the first value of each column in R?

Tags: r, loops, printing

I have the following data frame:

```
 Variable1  Variable2  Variable3  Variable4
 number1    number2    number3    number4
 gene1      gene2      gene4      gene5
            gene3
```

I would like the following rearrangement printed in a text file:

```
 gene1  number1
 gene2  number2
 gene3  number2
 gene4  number3
 gene5  number4
```

I tried to write the following loop function:

```
print <- function(dataframe){
 for (i in 2:nrow(dataframe))
  print(i)
}
```

So that I could use apply:

```
lapply(myDataFrame)
```

But it doesn't work. Basically, I want to write a loop function for one vector that will be applied to each column. However, it's not working. I would appreciate any pointer.

Comment: Try `melt` from `reshape2` package.

Comment: @user2472704.  Please check my update.  It seems like your columns are `factors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try, `melt` as suggested by @Roman Luštrik. If `dat` is the dataset

```
library(reshape2)  
res <- melt(as.matrix(setNames(dat[-1,], dat[1,])))[,-1]
res[res$value!='',2:1]
#  value    Var2
#1 gene1 number1
#3 gene2 number2
#4 gene3 number2
#5 gene4 number3
#7 gene5 number4
```

Or use `stack`

```
 subset(stack(setNames(dat[-1,], dat[1,])), values!='')
 # values     ind
#1  gene1 number1
#3  gene2 number2
#4  gene3 number2
#5  gene4 number3
#7  gene5 number4
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Variable1 = c("number1", "gene1", ""), Variable2 = c("number2", 
"gene2", "gene3"), Variable3 = c("number3", "gene4", ""), Variable4 = c("number4", 
"gene5", "")), .Names = c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", 
"Variable4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

#### Update

Suppose, if I convert `dat` columns to `factors`

```
 dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.factor)
  head(melt(as.matrix(setNames(dat[-1,], dat[1,])))[,-1],2)
 # Var2 value
 #1    3 gene1
 #2    3
```

So, it is better to convert the columns to 'character' class

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character)
 head(melt(as.matrix(setNames(dat[-1,], dat[1,])))[,-1],2)
 #     Var2 value
 #1 number1 gene1
 #2 number1
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for answering me back. However, when I use the first method (reshape), I get integers instead of my original numbers (i.e. in scientific notation).

Comment: setNames seems to be the problem: the numbers it combines are integers, instead of small numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: @user2472704.  Can you check `str` of your dataset.  I guess, the columns are `factors`.  In my example `dat`, the columns are `characters`.  When you read using read.table, use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to get character columns.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong: when I read the table's columns as characters. Now, everything works well! Thank you once again!